# Why does Inner Join introduce a hidden sort?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, join, sorting

Consider the following example:

```
DECLARE @suppliedNumber MONEY
SET @suppliedNumber = 245656.00

SELECT 
    ah.FirstName, 
    ah.LastName
FROM 
    AccountHolders AS ah
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Accounts] AS a
ON 
    ah.Id = a.AccountHolderId
GROUP BY 
    ah.FirstName, ah.LastName
HAVING SUM(a.Balance) > @suppliedNumber
```

As you can see there is no ordering of any kind in the query. But looking in the execution plan I see implicit sorting:

[image: SSMS Execution plan]

Why is this happening? What's the technical reason behind this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (RTM-CU14) (KB3158271) - 12.0.2569.0 (X64)   May 27 2016 15:06:08   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 14393: )

Comment: You are using `Group By` which this sort is helping with.

Comment: The Stream Aggregate operator requires sorted data. It's most likely for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @sp_BlitzErik mentioned in his comment, the [stream aggregate operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189907(v=sql.105).aspx) requires input to be sorted:

> The Stream Aggregate operator groups rows by one or more columns and then calculates one or more aggregate expressions returned by the query. The output of this operator can be referenced by later operators in the query, returned to the client, or both. **The Stream Aggregate operator requires input ordered by the columns within its groups. The optimizer will use a Sort operator prior to this operator if the data is not already sorted** due to a prior Sort operator or due to an ordered index seek or scan. In the SHOWPLAN_ALL statement or the graphical execution plan in SQL Server Management Studio, the columns in the GROUP BY predicate are listed in the Argument column, and the aggregate expressions are listed in the Defined Values column.

If you add an index on `FirstName, LastName` you may see the sort go away (if the query optimizer decides to use the index).

Answer (score 8):

I don't think the `join` is producing the sort

The `group by` `sum` is producing the sort
See the order by in the query plan

This might be faster
It breaks if the purpose is multiple accounts with same name

```
SELECT ah.Id, ah.FirstName, ah.LastName
FROM 
    AccountHolders AS ah
JOIN 
    [dbo].[Accounts] AS a
ON 
    ah.Id = a.AccountHolderId
GROUP BY 
    ah.Id, ah.FirstName, ah.LastName
HAVING SUM(a.Balance) > @suppliedNumber
```

Or

```
SELECT ah.Id, ah.FirstName, ah.LastName
FROM AccountHolders AS ah
JOIN ( select AccountHolderId
       from [dbo].[Accounts] A
       GROUP BY Id 
       HAVING SUM(Balance) > @suppliedNumber 
     ) a
 on a.AccountHolderId = ah.ID
```

Comment: Can you provide external document with detailed explanation on sorting & group by?

Comment: @iPathツ It is not intuitive to you that group by would likely use sort?  Take the group by and sum out and see if the sort goes away.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I need to provide that info to my teacher. He likes documents more than my intuition :) That's why I'm asking for external paper/blog that explains the situation in details.